# conditional statement if user enters integer instead of String

Tags: java

hey guys  I need help for my lab exercise. I need to just to pass through this question.. my only problem that I need to make sure that there will be an exception if user tries to enter a number(specifically int) in a String "but ** 
i am using `java.util.Scanner` and reading the input as a `String`

`else if (userInput.hasNextInt())` my problem only

the lab exercise saved as image
[image]

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quizbee{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score = 0;
        String userInput;
        String answerKey[] = {"A", "C", "B", "B", "C"}; //A, C, 

        String multichoice[][] = {{"A = Leonardo Da Vinci ", "B = Albert Einstein ","C = Stephen Hawking"},  //[0][0],[0][1],[0][2]
                                  {"A = 9 ", "B = 8 ", "C = 7 "},                                            //[1][0],[1][1],[1][2]
                                  {"A = Rodrigo Duterte ", "B = Ferdinand Marcos ", "C = Ninoy Aquino "},    //[2][0],[2][1],[2][2]
                                  {"A = John F. Kennedy ","B = Abraham Lincoln ","C = Ronald Reagan "},      //[3][0],[3][1],[3][2]
                                  {"A = Floyd Mayweather ","B = Manny Pacquaio ", "C = Muhammad Ali "}};     //[4][0],[4][1],[4][2]
                                      {}

        String arrQuestion[] = {"The Renaissance Man?", "prime number?","Longest-term serving Pres. of PH", 
                               "1st US President to be assassinated", "Nicknamed \"The Greatest\" in the boxing history"};


            for (int x = 0; x<arrQuestion.length; x++)
            {   
                try
                {   
                    System.out.println("\n" + (x+1)+". " + arrQuestion[x]); 
                    System.out.print(multichoice[x][0] + multichoice[x][1] + multichoice[x][2]+": "); 
                    userInput = sc.nextLine();


                    if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(answerKey[x]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                        score = score + 1;
                    } 

                    else if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(answerKey[x]))
                    {

                        if(userInput.isEmpty())
                        {
                            throw new NullPointerException();
                        }

                        else if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("A") && !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("B") && !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                        {
                            throw new OutOfRangeMisception();
                        }

                        else if(userInput.hasNextInt())
                        {
                            throw new InputMismatchException();
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wrong!");   
                            score = score + 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch(OutOfRangeMisception oor)
                {
                    System.out.println(oor.getMessage());       
                }

                catch(NullPointerException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("No answer. please try again.");     
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong data type.");
                }
            }
        System.out.println("\nYour score: " + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? or are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Welcome, I don't see a specific question, except the lab requirement. Even with a bad english (like mine ;) ) you could focus on the problem and create a [mcve]

Comment: Instead of `userInput.hasNextInt()` I would suggest `userInput.matches("\\d+")`. It checks whether the string contains digit.

Comment: Would `AABB123CC` be a valid input or should it be `AABBCC`?

Comment: In this type of codding, people use `switch`. And take input in form of a character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Integer.parseInt(userInput)`. If this succeeds, the user entered an integer, otherwise you get an exception. So if it is an integer you can throw your exception, otherwise you catch the `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple method to test if the `String` is number or not

```
public boolean isNumber(String text) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(text);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just Java, use[`StringUtils.isNumeric()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.String)):

> Checks if the String contains only unicode digits or space (' '). A decimal point is not a unicode digit and returns false.
>
> null will return false. An empty String (length()=0) will return true.

So in your case, you'd use:

```
else if(StringUtils.isNumeric(userInput))
```

Note that this *won't* work in Android. Instead you'll need [`TextUtils.isDigitsOnly()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence))